# Storing address of a local ipc buffer in below structure member and passing into ipcwrite cause data corruption

Tags: c, linux, struct, ipc

I am declaring a structure and one of the structure member is a pointer which store the address of IPC buffer .
The ipc_buffer is the local to one method and when I am passing the address of same buffer to another function and sending over IPCWrite() observing data corruption in IPC_recevie side ? 
Could anyone have pointer here why the data got corrupted ?

```
typedef struct ev_entry_s
{
    event_t ev_id;
    uint8_t *ipc_local_async_buff;
    uint32_t ev_data_size;
    uint8_t  ev_data[0];
}ev_entry_t;

fun_1()
{
    uint8_t      ipc_buffer[IPC_MAX_SEND_LEN]; 
    fun_2(&ipc_buffer); /*sending as a parameter */
}
fun_2(uin8_t *catch_pointer)
{
    ev_entry_t event_p;
    //Storing ipc_buffer addres in ipc_local_async_buff
    event_p.ipc_local_async_buff = catch_pointer; 
    fun_3(&event_p);
}
fun_3(ev_entry *event_p)
{
   /*sending the address of ipc_buffer over  IPCWrite*/

}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux processes do not share memory by default. Memory allocated for one process is not allocated for other processes.

Pointers are simply not sharable between processes.

You need to use *shared memory*. And not send pointers, but instead give a name to the shared memory segment so the other process can find it. Then use some other IPC mechanism to signal the other process that the memory can be read.

Comment: Thanks a Lot currently I am trying same .